# org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Unknown column 'postalCode' in 'field list'

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am using hibernate. When I try to insert values into my db I am getting error.

Here is the stack trace

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'postalCode' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
```

Here is a overview of my Pojo class

```
 @Entity 
    public class HeadOffice implements java.io.Serializable 
{


private Long officeId;  
private String name;    
private String addr1;   
private String addr2;   
private String postalCode;  
private String country;     
private String email;   
private String tel1;    
private String tel2;

public HeadOffice() { }

public String getPostalCode() 
{       
   return this.postalCode;  
}

public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) 
 {      
    this.postalCode = postalCode;   
     }
}
```

And this is the corresponding entry for the postal code property in the hbm.xml file

```
<property name="postalCode" type="string">
            <column name="postal_code" length="24" not-null="true" />
        </property>
```

during sql query exceqution the field name is taken as postalCode instead of postal_code

How can I correct this?
Thanks

Comment: How are you creating the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up annotation-style configuration and XML-style configuration. While this is possible, it's rarely the intention.

I suspect that your configuration is simply ignoring the `.hbm.xml` file and taking the config from your annotated class instead.

Try either:

1. removing `@Entity` from your class, or
2. adding `@Column(name="postal_code")` to the `getPostalCode()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if @Column annotation is added from javax.persistence 
Sometimes it is mistakenly imported from some other library